# allowing only access to TFS to external

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, security, group-policy

Recently I've found the need for allowing access to external people to my TFS server, but I have to be sure that they can't access others servers. This is what I've tried so far:

- Created a security group in domain called: 'external users - no login'
- Changed domain group policy 'Deny log on locally' to include this group
- Created a security group in domain called: 'external users - no network'
- Changed domaing group policy 'Deny access to this computer from the network' to include this group.
- Created the user and added to the two groups created before

All restrictions work fine, but also TFS server has become inaccesible to these users. Is there a way to simply deny access to any computer in the network, but let connect to TFS, like an exception, or something like that?

Comment: Are you talking about logging on locally through RDP, or consume the TFS web service through a browser or the Visual Studio integration?

Comment: TFS web service using Visual Studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the TFS server in its own OU.  In Group Policy Management Console, right-click the OU and select Block Inheritance.  You will need to explicitly link any GPO's to that OU that you need.

Probably a good idea to not have the restrictions in the Default Domain Group Policy.  Create a separate GPO for that.

Comment: why shouldn't alter the default GPO and create another one?. I'm quite new to this...

Comment: If your new security settings are in a separate GPO, you can link the other GPO's that you want to the OU where the TFS server is located.  It's generally not a good practice to ad-hoc add settings for the default domain and domain controllers GPO's.  What I do is review settings every few months, if there are settings that have persisted, consider rolling them up to the default GPO's if appropriate.